# Undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I have restricted one page from other users but if I am not logged in and visit that page, I get an error in the line `redirect_to '/' unless current_user.admin?`

but if I am logged in and visit the page,it works fine.
In my `Application` controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
def require_admin
    redirect_to '/' unless current_user.admin?
end
```

PLEASE can anyone tell me why is this error coming
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
current_user.try(:admin?)
```

This will check if current user is present

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are logged in your application and do the following:

```
def require_admin
  redirect_to root_path if current_user && current_user.admin?
end
```

Instead of writing redirect_to '/', you can use root_path to redirect to your home page.

Comment: Sorry for that...it does not show the error anymore but when admin is the user then also it was not showing the page..

Comment: then did you checked what is root_path in your case? since the condition is working fine it should redirect to '/'

Comment: ya it does not show any errors while using root_path or '/'..but admin was also not able to visit that page.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because you're not signed in, so your `current_user` method returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that current_user is always a user instance, or check that it's not nil:

```
if current_user && current_user.admin?
```

You could alternatively use  `current_user.try(:admin?)` and it will fail silently if current_user is nil.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
 def require_admin
   redirect_to '/' if current_user && current_user.admin?
 end
```